# How to solve the problem of overlap in absolute position element

Tags: css

On medium devices the hello 2 which is the second column is made to go below Hello1.

The section 2 doesn't move as a relative positioned element should and so it gets overlapped by Hello2.
I do not want to use background-image url and want to solve this issue using the image src.
The section 2 should start from where the content of the second col-md-6 ends
Is it possible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <style type="text/css">
  .header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 83vh;
  }
  .header {
   position: relative;
  }
  .header-content {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px 
  }
  h1 {
   color: steelblue;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
 <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kdsPrQt.jpg">
</div>
<div class="header-content">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <h1>Hello1</h1>
  <h1>Hello1</h1>
  <h1>Hello1</h1>
  <h1>Hello1</h1>
  <h1>Hello1</h1>
  <h1>Hello1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <h1>Hello2</h1>
     <h1>Hello2</h1>
     <h1>Hello2</h1>
     <h1>Hello2</h1>
     <h1>Hello2</h1>
     <h1>Hello2</h1>
     <h1>Hello2</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<section>
 <h2>This is section 2</h2>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's the problem? You've told us what the current situation is, but not what you want the outcome to be...

Comment: your question is not clear. please tell us what help you want from us. thansk

Comment: `position:absolute` removes the element from the normal document flow and positions it relative to the nearest ancestor with `position:relative` or `body` if there is no suitable ancestor. In your case is is `body` as `header content is a direct descendant of `body` . Further more "Section 2" is not relatively positioned as you have not applied any style to it so it is effectively `position:static`

Comment: The section 2 should start from where the content of the second col-md-6 ends

Comment: Why don't you make the content statically positioned so it maintains its natural flow and use absolute positioning on the image in the background?